# Fermi energy for a fermion gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, fermions

I came across an old exam question for my statistical mechanics course:

Let the energy levels of a gas of $N$ fermions be given as $$\varepsilon_n = (n+1)^{\alpha} \  \varepsilon_0  \ ,  \ \   n = 0,1,2... \ \text{and  } \alpha > 1  $$, with each level having degeneracy :

$$ g_n = (n+1)^{\beta} ,\ \  \beta > 1  $$

Calculate the Fermi energy , and the total average energy in the limit $N >> 1$.

What I've tried

Since $N \rightarrow \infty$ we can use the grand canonical ensemble. The average number of particles that occupies the $n$th orbital is (?):

$$ \langle N_n \rangle = \dfrac{g(n)}{e^{\beta{(\varepsilon_n + \mu)  }} +1  }  $$

Hence the total number of particles is:

$$ N = \sum^{\infty}_n \langle N_n \rangle $$

If $g(n) = g$ (i.e. same degeneracy for every level) , the sum can be written as an integral over the momenta $\vec{p}$:

$$ \sum_n = g\sum_{\vec{p}} =  g\dfrac{V}{h^3} \int d^3p $$

In the limit $T \rightarrow 0$ , we find:

$$ \dfrac{1}{e^{\beta{(\varepsilon_n + \mu)  }} +1  } \rightarrow \Theta(\varepsilon_F - \varepsilon)  $$ ($\Theta$ being the Heaviside stepfunction, and $\varepsilon_F$ the Fermi energy), hence in the same limit, for $g_n = g$ we have:

$$ N = \sum^{\infty}_n \langle N_n \rangle =  g\dfrac{V}{h^3} \int \Theta(\varepsilon_F - \varepsilon) d^3p  $$

The integral is just volume of the ball with radius $p_F = \sqrt{2m \varepsilon_F}$...

What to do if $g_n$ is not constant ?

We get the integral (?):

$$ \dfrac{V}{h^3} \int d^3  p \  \Theta(\varepsilon_F - \varepsilon)   g(n)  $$

I'm not quite sure what to do here...

Comment: I suppose this problem corresponds to a three-dimensional ideal gas in the case of $\alpha = \beta = 2$. But you don't really need this correspondence. I think that due to the lack of volume in this problem, inverse temperature and chemical potential have a scaling like $\beta \sim 1/N^\gamma$, $\mu \sim N^\delta$ and it is possible to consider $\sum_n$ as $\int dn$.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of zero temperature, fermions occupy states with lower energy. Thus, the equation for the number $n_{\text{max}}$ of the occupied state with the highest energy has the form
$$
N \approx \sum_{n=0}^{n_{\text{max}}} g_n
$$
Condition $N \gg 1$ leads to $n_{\text{max}} \gg 1$. The relative change of the power function is slow in the domain of large arguments: $(n+1)^\beta / n^\beta \approx 1$ for $n \gg 1$. Therefore, the equation for $n_{\text{max}}$ can be written as
$$
N \approx \int_0^{n_{\text{max}}} (n+1)^\beta\ dn \approx \frac1{\beta+1} (n_{\text{max}}+1)^\beta.
$$
So we have
$$
n_{\text{max}}+1 \approx (N(\beta+1))^{\frac1{\beta+1}}
$$
and
$$
\varepsilon_{\text{F}} = \varepsilon_0 (n_{\text{max}} + 1)^\alpha \approx \varepsilon_0 (N(\beta+1))^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta+1}}
$$